# Why my selenium/codeception test sometimes freezes?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, codeception, acceptance

I'm in a process of writing acceptance tests of company's web application. What I'm using is Codeception with Webdriver and Firefox browser. I have a problem I cannot resolve despite hours and hours of searching.

The question is simple: Why my test *sometimes freezes in one point* for so long (about 5 minutes). After that it continues and works like a charm.

This is Selenium output:

```
14:18:27.515 INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.linkText: Loads])
14:23:04.375 INFO - Done: [find elements: By.linkText: Loads]
```

To make things even more interesting I can say that *sometimes* it goes by very fast. 
Desired element is present and visible in browser window - it is simple span with "Loads" text, and this is command I use:

```
$I->click(['link'=>"Loads"]);
```

Comment: What version of Selenium Webdriver are you running with what version of Firefox? Also, I do all my locators by #id, rarely by .class and even rarely by text link. Even when I have to $I->see('something', ['id' => 'I Pass a ID here']);. I find the locators by anything other then ID to suck bad. Not 5 minutes suck though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All my software is up-to-date. Selenium webdriver 2.52, Firefox 44.0.2, Codeception 2.1.6. Unfortunately I am not able to use #ids cause they are not constant in my app.

Comment: Can you at least try to put an ID on that specific element which is sometimes hanging and see if it improves? You could also write better xpath locators instead of just passing a class.